# Pyspark use of Map() within a while loop with conditional logic always returns else

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I basically only ever get back the else in the below what am I doing wrong?

```
StageSource6RDD = StageSource6.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], \
                                                              stage_CombinedStage if stage_01_MaxRow == stage_CombinedStage else x[1],\
                                                              stage_CombinedStage if stage_02_MaxRow == stage_CombinedStage else x[2],\
                                                              stage_CombinedStage if stage_03_MaxRow == stage_CombinedStage else x[3],\
                                                              stage_CombinedStage if stage_04_MaxRow == stage_CombinedStage else x[4],\
                                                              stage_CombinedStage if stage_05_MaxRow == stage_CombinedStage else x[5],\
                                                              stage_CombinedStage if stage_06_MaxRow == stage_CombinedStage else x[6],\
                                                              stage_CombinedStage if stage_07_MaxRow == stage_CombinedStage else x[7],\
                                                              stage_CombinedStage if stage_08_MaxRow == stage_CombinedStage else x[8],\
                                                              stage_CombinedStage if stage_09_MaxRow == stage_CombinedStage else x[9],\
                                                              stage_CombinedStage if stage_10_MaxRow == stage_CombinedStage else x[10]))
```

Comment: How do you calculate `stage_??_MaxRow` and `stage_CombinedStage`? Can you post some more of the code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: ```stage_01_MaxRow = maxRow.collect()[counter3-1][1]
    stage_02_MaxRow = maxRow.collect()[counter3-1][2]
    stage_03_MaxRow = maxRow.collect()[counter3-1][3]
    stage_04_MaxRow = maxRow.collect()[counter3-1][4]
    stage_05_MaxRow = maxRow.collect()[counter3-1][5]
    stage_06_MaxRow = maxRow.collect()[counter3-1][6]
    stage_07_MaxRow = maxRow.collect()[counter3-1][7]
    stage_08_MaxRow = maxRow.collect()[counter3-1][8]
    stage_09_MaxRow = maxRow.collect()[counter3-1][9]
    stage_10_MaxRow = maxRow.collect()[counter3-1][10] ```

Comment: currentRow = spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM tmpStageSource3 WHERE row_number = {counter}")
        
        
        
        currentRow.createOrReplaceTempView('tmpcurrentRow')
        combinedStage = spark.sql("""SELECT  stack(10, stage_01, stage_02, stage_03, stage_04, stage_05, stage_06, stage_07, stage_08, stage_09, stage_10) as combinedStage ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY combinedStage DESC) AS RowNo  FROM tmpcurrentRow""")
        
        
        combinedStage.createOrReplaceTempView('tmpcombinedStage')

Comment: combinedStage.createOrReplaceTempView('tmpcombinedStage')
        
        
        
        counter2 = 1
        comboCounter = 1
        Threshold2 = combinedStage.select(max('RowNo')).first()[0]
        if Threshold2 is None:
            Threshold2 = 0
        while counter2 <= Threshold2:
            
            
            stage_CombinedStage = combinedStage.collect()[comboCounter-1][0]
            if stage_CombinedStage is None:
                stage_CombinedStage = "Blank"

Comment: Just want to also add I'm new to Stackoverflow and Pyspark

Comment: Note. I can do this correctly with a delta table using case when statements in an update statement. It just runs extremely slow. Like hours slow. The same script in SQL server runs in 11 sec. I have tried vacuum and optimize on the delta table with no luck. If I could solve the delta table performance issue we can ignore the above. Which ever is easier. But its the 100+ snap shots that are created each time the while loops run.

Comment: This as been solved going about it from a different angle